# How do you bust cache for angular views using PhoneGap?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, caching

I have fully bought into the benefits of using angular and have a a hybrid app (using PhoneGap) I'm going to convert over (from Jquery Mobile) but I'm having a problem figuring out how to get my new code to the app.

The app is currently hosted on our website (NOT local to the device) so normal caching works as expected. I update a web page or js and the app sees the new content (because the underlying webview/browser knows its new content).

But with angular's SPA approach the main module gets loaded up front and changes views based on loading new partials. Also not a problem.

BUT, what happens when I change my app module (the code loaded by ng-app="demo")? Such as adding new routes, controllers, or views.

Since that's already loaded in the browser at bootstrap how do I tell the app there are changes and it needs to reload the overall app?

There are 3 use cases to consider:

1) On a PC/browser you can just refresh the page. I can't depend on users knowing to do that but its not as bad because users are likely to open and close their browser thus reloading the new app/js.

2) When I issue a new PhoneGap app (to the app stores) it forces a browser close/reopen during the installation, so the user will get the new code.

3) THIS IS THE REAL STICKLER. During normal use of the PhoneGap app users may open the app and NEVER close it again (merely suspending and reopening). These are not tech-savvy users and might not even know how to restart an app never mind realize they should try.

So what's the angular way to force the app the refresh when the base app module has changed?

Or am I on my own to create some type of version checking system to force a reload() when I need it.

Seems like a common situation to me but everything I find on caching with angular says something to this effect:

"Since you probably want to maintain browser caching for your views, partials or other routes"

No I don't - I WANT to bust cache for my app/views/controller because i know it has changed.

angular phonegap cache buster

Comment: can't you just set up a version number and service to periodically check for updates?

Comment: That is what I meant by: "Or am I on my own to create some type of version checking system to force a reload() when I need it."

I'm trying to ascertain if there is a real angular way to do it. Seems like a common problem to me - I would think EVERY angular app has to be updated at some point.

My situation is just compicated by the fact that its a PhoneGap app so the user can't just hit refresh

Comment: Well managing updates falls solely on you and your app. Seems like a trivial problem to me

Comment: "Well managing updates falls solely on you and your app."

I disagree, I don't have to worry about it with normal js and html - angular is adding this burden. No matter how trivial ts one more thing I didn't have to do before.

Comment: Why is angular the problem? If any page is left open indefinitely the problem is the same

Comment: This is not just when the page is left open, its when the user clicks something and angular loads the new partial(s) its doing so with the currently loaded app/controllers not the new ones. Maybe you knwo the mechanism better than me.

Or is every partial supposed to load its own controller scripts. That's not the way I've seen anyone doing it.

When that happens in normal browser the page and its associated js are loaded from the server, the browser knows its new and reloads it.

Nothing tells angular it has itself changed.

How does it know to reload itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74855/discussion-between-jwleigh-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could dynamically load/unload your controllers on each use. [This article](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs) should get you started.

Comment: And, on the subject of views, you should just be able to disable the templateCache via this technique: http://opensourcesoftwareandme.blogspot.com/2014/02/safely-prevent-template-caching-in-angularjs.html

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. I've looked at a lot of his stuff, not sure how I missed that one.